# Hierarchical module name for type-level programs

Tags: haskell, module, type-families, data-kinds

So let's say I wrote some [type-level program](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-families.html#synonym-families) in Haskell:

```
type family NAryFn (n::Nat) (dom::*) (cod::*) :: *
type instance NAryFn Ze dom cod = cod
type instance NAryFn (Su n) dom cod = dom -> NAryFn n dom cod
```

I think this is useful and I want to use it all over my project.  So I put it in a module.

What would be a good hierarchical name for the module? (c.f. [Haskell Hierarchical Modules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/))

A lot of data structures live in `Data` (`Data.Text`, `Data.List`, etc), various ways of structuring effects are in `Control` such as `Control.Monad` or `Control.Applicative`.

Where should type-level programs live?  `Type`? `TypeFamily`? Has consensus developed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked on hackage, and most packages providing type level functionality live in the `Data` hierarchy, under `Data.Type`, `Data.TypeLevel` or the like, or sometimes `Data.Number.Etc.TypeLevel`. There are a few exceptions though.

The type-level-natural-number package lives under TypeLevel: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-level-natural-number

The tfp package lives under Types: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tfp

A number of nicolas frisby's packages live under Type: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-booleans and http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-cereal for example.

So there's no consensus at the moment, apparently. Personally I think `Types` is the appropriate place for all this stuff to go, but as is usual with the Haskell community, everything ends to end up in `Data`.

The perils of a language where nearly everything is first class, I suppose :-)

You can see some, but not all, of the type-level packages in the "Type System" category on hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat:type%20system